# sql - multiple values to test function

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to test out a function (in this case - regexp_replace(tvalue,'([[:cntrl:]])','')) and was wondering if there is a way to go through multiple input data to a function in one SQL query?

basically i want to see that a function is replacing non-printable characters, my idea was something like the below:

my pseudocode:

```
with testdata as (select 
'teststring1',
'$kfjs',
chr(10)||'test',
'    <>',
null,
'[{}&,''/\'
from dual)
select tvalue, regexp_replace(tvalue,'([[:cntrl:]])','')  from testdata
where tvalue <> regexp_replace(tvalue,'([[:cntrl:]])','');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with testdata as (
  select 'teststring1' as tvalue from dual
  union all
  select '$kfjs' from dual
  union all
  select 'str1' || chr(10) || 'str2' from dual
  union all
  select '    <>' from dual
  union all
  select null from dual
  union all
  select '[{}&,''/' from dual
)
select rownum, tvalue, regexp_replace(tvalue, '([[:cntrl:]])', '') from testdata
where tvalue <> regexp_replace(tvalue, '([[:cntrl:]])', '');
```

Comment: do u know of another method that doesn't require using the good ol' union for each string I want to test?

Comment: @toop - what's your object to the UNION operator?

Comment: Although, in this case UNION ALL is better than UNION, because we don't need to winnow out duplicates, so we can save ourselves a sort operation.

Comment: @toop: You could probably write a table function to do the same thing, I'm not sure if that's better/easier or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a user-defined datatype, you can use that type as a constructor with the `table` function to produce a set of values.

```
CREATE TYPE test_data AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(40);

SELECT COLUMN_VALUE, REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN_VALUE, '([[:cntrl:]])', '')
FROM   table(test_data(
                'teststring1',
                '$kfjs',
                CHR(10) || 'test',
                '    <>',
                NULL,
                '[{}&,''/\'
             ))
WHERE  COLUMN_VALUE <> REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN_VALUE, '([[:cntrl:]])', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

it is simple. Create a table in database named testdata, add your cases in it, and then run your query:

```
select rownum, tvalue, regexp_replace(tvalue, '([[:cntrl:]])', '') 
from testdata
where tvalue <> regexp_replace(tvalue, '([[:cntrl:]])', '')
```